# Generate FLV Video File with ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flv

I'm working on Flash ActionScript.
My Movie Load some data like photo, sounds and photo to the Movie Stage. Each of loaded MovieClip have own animation.

Is it possible to generate (record) FLV or other Movie file from ActionScript with ActionScript?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an FLV writer written in pure Actionscript 3
http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/

Comment: this is a library for AIR. is it able to be used to create flash embed in a web page? coz this library is writing to local file, and flash embed can't do so. I want to create a slideshow creator for web.

Comment: Yes it is possible to embed the library in flash: in fla file hit in the right bar action script settings > library path tab > hit browse swc file button and browse for the location of the component! After that in the .as file use ` import com.dd.screencapture.ScreenCapture;
 import com.dd.screencapture.SimpleFlvWriter;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's an AS library for that, but you can take a look to [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)'s [hxFormat](http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/) which has FLV support (you can read and write FLV files).

Keep in mind though, that if you run your app within the browser you'll need server side support for actually writing the files.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of app you are building. I have in the past used flash to create a video conversion app by piggy-backin on top of ffmpeg. (so really it was ffmpeg doing the actual conversion work) But it was my flash app that allowed people to drag and drop the file and select the output format etc.

Basically I built my app using flash and compiled it using Zinc 2.5. So basically all the functional was done in AS but again, the actual performing of the conversion was done by the ffmpeg binary based on the commands sent to it from the flash app.

Answer (score -1):

Moyea software ( http://www.moyea.com/ ) makes, or used to make, an app that will capture video from an actionscripted Flash movie at whatever frame rate you want.

It was simple and perfect for my purposes when I used it and the video quality was good enough for commercial use.

Comment: Are you affiliated with that product?